# How to access data from a dynamic Table

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, react-props, use-effect

Presently learning to code and I have done some work here...

Using MongoDB I hardcoded some data (transactions) retrieved them into a table in the front-end.

In other to do this, I created a js file called TransactionItems and listed the properties of interest like this.

```js
import React   from 'react';
import {Badge} from "reactstrap";




  const TransactionItem = props =>{

  
    return (

     

    <>
       
      <td>{props.transaction.date}</td>
      <td> {props.transaction.amount}</td>
      <td>{props.transaction.token}</td>
      <td>{props.transaction._id}</td>
  
      <td className="text-right"><Badge color="warning"  >
        View
      </Badge>
      </td> 
    </>
    )
}

export default TransactionItem;
```

I also created a Service connecting to my backend

```js
getTransactions : ()=>{
        return fetch('/user/transactions')
                .then(response=>{
                    if(response.status !== 401){
                        return response.json().then(data => data);
                    }
                    else
                        return {message : {msgBody : "UnAuthorized",msgError : true}};
                });
    },
```

Then on my Dashboard, I populated a table with data like this

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import TransactionItem from '../views/TransactionItems';
import TransactionService from '../Services/TransactionService';
import { Col, Row, Card, CardTitle, CardText, CardBody, CardFooter, CardHeader, Button, Table } from 'reactstrap';




const Dashboard = props=>{
  const [user,setUser] = useState([]);
  const [transactions,setTransactions] = useState([]);


  
 

  useEffect(()=>{
        TransactionService.getTransactions().then(data =>{
            setTransactions(data.transactions);
        
        });
      },[]);








    
  return (
 
    <>
      
                <Table responsive>
                  <thead className=" text-warning">
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                        Date
                      </th>
                      <th>
                        Amount
                      </th>
                      <th>
                        Token
                      </th>
                      <th>
                        Receipt No
                      </th>
                      <th className="text-right">
                        Action
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     {
                                transactions.map(transaction  =>{
                                    return  (<tr><TransactionItem key={transaction._id} transaction={transaction} loading={loading}/>

                                             </tr>)
                                })
                            }
                  </tbody>
                </Table>
        

      </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

When populated it looks like this
[image]

I have created a receipt sample for each transaction

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState}from 'react';
import {Row, Container} from "reactstrap";
import AuthService from '../Services/AuthService';
import TransactionService from '../Services/TransactionService';

 


function Receipt(props) {

  const [user,setUser] = useState([]);
  const [transaction,setTransaction] = useState();
  
  const id = ''; 

  useEffect(()=>{
    AuthService.isAuthenticated().then(data =>{
     setUser(data.user);
     });
   },[]);


useEffect(()=>{
     TransactionService.getTransaction(id).then(data =>{
      console.log(data);
         setTransaction(data.transaction);
     });
   },[id]);



    return (
        <div>
            <>
      
                
                   <div style={{color: 'RGB(128, 128, 128)', fontSize: '1rem', 
                        fontWeight: '600', 
                        textAlign: 'left',
                        justifyContent: 'center',  
                        alignContent: 'center'}}>Token Credit:</div>
             
            </>  
   
        </div>
    );
}

export default Receipt;
```

and created the route on the back end to access each transaction object using the transaction _id. I tried to execute it by also creating a service for this in the front end

```js
getTransaction : (id)=>{
        return fetch('/user/'+id)
      
                .then(response=>{
                    console.log(response.data);
                    if(response.status !== 401){
                        return response.json().then(data => data);
                    }
                    else
                        return {message : {msgBody : "UnAuthorized",msgError : true}};
                });
    },

}
```

and when tested with a known transaction_id it worked(I console logged the response). But I am not sure how to pass the _id for each transaction on the table such that when the view button is clicked it opens the receipt page and set the state id on the receipt page to the transaction_id of the transaction object, using UseEffect.

Any pointer will be most helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution that worked here

Step 1
Bring in useHistory hook

```js
import { useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Step 2
Define history inside TransactionItem object.

```js
let history = useHistory();
```

Step 3 
Also define viewRow as such in the inside TransactionItem object.

```js
const viewRow = (e) =>{
       e.preventDefault();
       history.push('/receipt/'+ props.transaction._id);
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Hı ,

you can pass _id with local storage . in view click action , Save _id info in local storage and redirect to receipt page.  in receipt page get    _id  from local storage like this.

```
// setter
localStorage.setItem('myData', data);

// getter
localStorage.getItem('myData');

// remove
localStorage.removeItem('myData');
```

Now look this example :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Table extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props) 
      this.state = {
         students: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Wasif', age: 21, email: 'wasif@email.com' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Ali', age: 19, email: 'ali@email.com' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Saad', age: 16, email: 'saad@email.com' },
            { id: 4, name: 'Asad', age: 25, email: 'asad@email.com' }
         ]
      }
   }

   viewRow(id,e) {
     alert('selectedId:'+ id);
     localStorage.setItem('transactionId',id);
    }


   renderTableData() {
      return this.state.students.map((student, index) => {
         const { id, name, age, email } = student //destructuring
         return (
            <tr key={id}>
               <td>{id}</td>
               <td>{name}</td>
               <td>{age}</td>
               <td>{email}</td>
               <td><button onClick={(e) => this.viewRow(id, e)}>View</button></td>
            </tr>
         )
      })
   }


   render() { 
      return (
         <div>
            <h1 id='title'>React Dynamic Table</h1>
            <table id='students'>
               <tbody>
                  {this.renderTableData()}
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

export default Table;
```

I add view button in table and also add viewRow metod.  When  button clicked, ı get selectedRow id and save in localstorage.

[image]

Comment: @Bahiyar. in my TransactionItem I tried saving the transaction._id  to the local storage like this ...   localStorage.setItem('transaction._id', props.transaction._id); but I get the error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'transaction._id')

Comment: Here is some example for  using local storage in useEffect . it is simple. are you sure props.transaction._id have value ?  look examples :https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react

Comment: I don't think I am still getting it. Yes, I don't think props.transaction._id has a value. Since its just a transaction item that is actually set in the dashboard. So again after reading the link you sent, the best  i could comeup with still gave errors. Error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id" for model "Transaction"

Comment: in the transactionItem, I included this  const[_id, set_ID] = useState('');
   
 
    const handleBadgeClick = (event) => {

      localStorage.setItem('transaction._id', _id);
      set_ID(_id);
    
  
   
      }
    then on the receipt I tried this  const [_id, set_ID] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem('transaction') || ''
  );
 

  const id = _id; 

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('transaction._id', _id);
  
  }, [_id]);

Comment: I made simple example and I edited my  previous answer.Look at the new answer.

Comment: the error is still the same. Error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id" for model "Transaction". _id is generated by the database(MongoDb) and it's not written in my model